# List item attachments not showing up when accessed through the object model

Tags: 2010, object-model, attachments

I've got some list items which have manually attached (through the web interface) files and need to access these files on server-side. Whenever I look at SPListItem.Attachments though, it always shows up as empty, regardless of whether the item has an attachement or not. Can anyone think why this might be the case?

Comment: Is this by chance an item that requires approval and is the ID that you are using to access it via the object model authorized to see unpublished versions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "requires approval". I can access the list item through the object model without issue, it's just the attachements I'm having trouble with.

Comment: I know this is two years old, but any chance you remember what happened? I'm facing the same problem on SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, I'm afraid - I don't even remember which area of the system I was working on at the time! I'll have a dig around the old code though and update accordingly.